# How to do display columns with string in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

[image: sample input]

Have to output companies who have greater than 10,000 employees in the format: COMPANY.ID

This is what I've written so far

```
SELECT NAME,ID
FROM COMPANY
WHERE EMPLOYEES > 10000
ORDER BY EMPLOYEES ASC;
```

My output is COMPANY ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT` to generate the output you want:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(NAME, '.', ID) AS RESULT
FROM COMPANY
WHERE EMPLOYEES > 10000
ORDER BY EMPLOYEES;
```